# Video onto a website without plugins

Tags: html, video, encoding, web

After reading about MP4 and .ogv file conversions and all manner of video players, i'm really confused - I have read that HTML5 can be used to do this. My skills on the web are limited so any help would be great.

I have a video file that I want to embed onto a website - it needs to be viewable on both IE and Safari and if possible WITHOUT the user needing to install plugins.  What do I need to do to complete this / is there a way?

Any insights / links would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HTML5 to achieve this, but you need to have the video in different formats for different browsers. I also suggest having a flash fallback for older browsers that don't support the video element.

[Here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-html-5-video-with-a-fallback-to-flash/) is a quick guide on HTML5 video with a flash fallback.

You could also try looking into [videojs](http://videojs.com/), which seems to do most of the work for you.

Comment: Hi grc,  Thank you for your help - checked out the links you kindly provided and feel much more comfortable on the matter, think there is definitely something to work with there!  Many thanks!