# Best way of posting a video to a html website

Tags: html, video

I want to post some mp4 videos in my site and I don't want to upload it to youtube or any 3rd party web app which will let me embed it into my website. I also don't want to use any blogging system like wordpress, drupal. So then what is the best way to post it to my site so that most devices will be able to view it. And can I customize the player which I use?
I have seen w3schools html5 video but I didn't find it helpful. I have also seen ' [Video onto a website without plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056289/video-onto-a-website-without-plugins) ' but I am not satisfied with that.
[Hint: I am ready to convert my video into any format required.]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Video onto a website without plugins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056289/video-onto-a-website-without-plugins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used video.js for this purpose, it worked for me. I haven't tried editing it much, but it has options.
http://www.videojs.com

Answer (score 1):

Use the HTML 5 video element. You'll have to upload your video in different formats, since there is no video format that is supported by all browsers, but support for the video element itself is quite good. IE8 doesn't support it, but IE8 is already very old. With the video tag you don't need Javascript or flash plugins.

For an overview of browser support see [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=video). Another source with much detailed information about video formats and how to convert them is [DiveIntoHTML5.info](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html).

Comment: Thanks GolezTrol, it is very helpful.